# Flutter PositionedTapDetector not working with stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart

When using the code without the stack, the PositionedTapDetector input area was the container. However, when I've added the code notes (//)
the input area was decreased to the vertex widget(which is smaller).
** _vertex/_edges are hash set of a Vertex/Edges, witch are widget of containers/Line.

```
GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        // color: Colors.red,
        child: PositionedTapDetector(
          onDoubleTap: (position) {
            setState(() {
              double dx = position.relative.dx;
              double dy = position.relative.dy;
              Vertex v = new Vertex(posX: dx / 1920, posY: dy / 1920);
              this.addVertex(v);
            });
          },
          // child: Stack(
          //   children: [
          //     Stack(
          //       children: _edges.toList(),
          //     ),
          //     Stack(
          //       children: _vertex.toList(),
          //     ),
          //   ],
          // ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution that I found:

by adding to PositionedTapDetector
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,